# Setting datePicker (That is set to time mode) with a string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a string in this form : "h:mm a" and im trying to set a date picker to that time. I have tried this :

```
NSDate *exampleDateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"];
datepicker.date = exampleDateFromString;
```

But it didn't work, is this because you are not able to set a date from  a string? Or am I doing it wrong? If so, how do I do it right?

---

## Edit

I tried this too:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    NSDate *exampleDateFromString = @"8:48 AM"];
    datepicker.date = exampleDateFromString;
```

My date picker is

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datepicker.minuteInterval = 5;
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(picker1Changed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

## Edit

The problem was setting the date before I allocated and initiated the picker. Sorry all for the trouble.

Comment: Want to know one thing,On above code you have allocated your date picker with frame size width and height as 0.Are you able to see the picker on your iPhone screen.

Comment: Yes, and this is probably because i'm actually using the date picker as a keyboard

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
 dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

 NSDate *exampleDateFromString =[dateFormat dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"]; 
 [datepicker setDate:exampleDateFromString]
```

If this does not work it means that you have not set `datepicker` as an `oultet`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first to clarify:

`NSDate` is a Objective-C class for holding date, and

`NSDateFormatter` is a Objective-C class for setting and changing date format

So what you want to do is this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    NSDate *exampleDateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"];
    datepicker.date = exampleDateFromString;
```

This should do the trick.

The point is that you set your data format in `NSDateFormatter`, and use its methods to return `NSDate` from data string (i.e 8:48 AM) in the format you've described.

Comment: Maybe changing `datepicker.date = exampleDateFromString` to `[datepicker setDate:exampleDateFromString];` could help?

Also, could you please provide more code you use, as the datepicker allocation and such?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a well-defined locale, otherwise the format "h:mm a" might be interpreted
in some locale-dependent way:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *exampleDateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"];
datepicker.date = exampleDateFromString;
```

Comment: @user2757277: Strange, it works without problems in my test program. - What exactly does not work in your case? Is `exampleDateFromString = nil`? Or is `exampleDateFromString` correct, but the picker does not display what you expect?

Comment: What happens is the datePicker is just set to the actual time

Answer (score -1):

Try THis...it will work

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
  dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
  NSDate *exampleDateFromString =[dateFormat dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"]; 
  date-picker.minimumDate=exampleDateFromString;
 [date-picker setDate:exampleDateFromString];
```